# Android imageview not behaving with setAlpha for transparent image

Tags: android

I have a view that I am dynamically adding two ImageView elements to at runtime before adding the view to the parent container to display it. On drag events, I want to set the image transparency to hidden or shown depending on the direction of move. I am trying to use imageView.setAlpha(0) to make the image invisible but even though the code is being called, the images stay visible or partly visible from when their alpha value was changed earlier to say 0.5.

Is there any reason an ImageView would refuse to trigger on a programmatic setAlpha()?

Comment: have you considered using setVisibility() instead?

Comment: `set the image transparency to hidden or shown` is confusing... did you mean `set the image visibility to hidden or shown`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it to 0.0. To change the opacity, you need to use the `setAlpha(float)` not `setAlpha(int)`

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. I was calling setAlpha(0) - changed to setAlpha((float)0) and it works perfectly. Annoying that they have a call for setAlpha(int) that does nothing